# How to call time-dependent hamiltonian with qutip/python?

Tags: python, qutip

I am trying to implement some codes to describe the coherent control of a system. The problem is that I want to use an hamiltonian of the form:
{H}_ij = u(t) * h_ij * exp(omega_ij * t) for the i^th row and j^th column
with h_ij = conj(h_ji) and h_ii = 0.
Because the time dependence of each terms is different, this hamiltonian cannot be written using the techniques to write a time-dependent hamiltonian with the first three options detailed in the user manual (http://qutip.org/downloads/4.4.0/qutip-doc-4.4.pdf#subsection.3.5.6) more precisely at page 61.

It can however be realized with the fourth (outdated) option:

> Finally option #4, expressing the Hamiltonian as a Python function, is
>   the original method for time dependence in QuTiP 1.x. However, this 
>   method is somewhat less efficient then the previously mentioned methods. 
>   However, in contrast to the other options this method can be used in 
>   implementing time-dependent Hamiltonians that cannot be expressed as a 
>   function of constant operators with time-dependent coefficients.

I think this is exactly what I want but I don't understand how I can implement the Hamiltonian as a python function.
Can someone show me an example of such "Hamiltonian as a Python function"?

EDIT:
This is what I've tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
import qutip


psi_0 = qutip.ket2dm(qutip.basis(2, 0))
psi_1 = qutip.ket2dm(qutip.basis(2, 1))
time = np.linspace(0, 10)

H_zeros = qutip.Qobj([[0, 0], [0, 0]])


def Hamiltonian_1(t, args):
    return [[0, np.exp(1j * t)], [np.exp(- 1j * t), 0]]


def Hamiltonian_2(t):
    return [[0, np.exp(1j * t)], [np.exp(- 1j * t), 0]]


def Hamiltonian_3(t, args):
    return qutip.Qobj([[0, np.exp(1j * t)], [np.exp(- 1j * t), 0]])


def Hamiltonian_4(t):
    return qutip.Qobj([[0, np.exp(1j * t)], [np.exp(- 1j * t), 0]])


# result = qutip.mesolve(Hamiltonian_1, psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve(Hamiltonian_2, psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve(Hamiltonian_3, psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve(Hamiltonian_4, psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([Hamiltonian_1], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([Hamiltonian_2], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([Hamiltonian_3], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([Hamiltonian_4], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([H_zeros, Hamiltonian_1], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([H_zeros, Hamiltonian_2], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([H_zeros, Hamiltonian_3], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([H_zeros, Hamiltonian_4], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([H_zeros, [H_zeros, Hamiltonian_1]], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([H_zeros, [H_zeros, Hamiltonian_2]], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([H_zeros, [H_zeros, Hamiltonian_3]], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
# result = qutip.mesolve([H_zeros, [H_zeros, Hamiltonian_4]], psi_0, time, [], [psi_0, psi_1])
```

I've tried in this simple case with different definitions of the hamiltonian function (Hamiltonian_1 to 4) and I've tried multiple combination of mesolve functions (commented in this code for the moment)... None of them is working.

Thank you,
Paul

Comment: pretty much means you're going to have to write your own function for the hamiltonian. you can use numpy/scipy for that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply.

Actually, that is what I've understood as well but I don't know how to implement such a function.
I've editted what I've tried and did not work for different reasons in the main comment.
Paul